# scp Permission Denied

Tags: 16.04, ssh, scp

`scp` was working. After I added LetsEncrypt it wasn't.

Probably LetsEncrypt added new rsa key and i don't have it. If that's the problem how can i find it.

I'm Trying

```
scp ~/Downloads/filename  remote@host:/folder/folder2
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Edit#1 I will Reinstall My Server.

Comment: sry, didn't use sudo. I will edit it

Comment: I have setup my server to login only with ssh. SSH is working and i have access to my server. But when I Installed LetsEncrypt to add https on my domains. scp not working anymore. I get this message Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: try running it again with -v to get more info on the failure and add it to your question

Comment: Its the private key the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this :`scp -r /local_path/uptofile remote_user@host:/Path/`

Comment: Already Tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: scp -v /local_path/uptofile remote_user@host:/Path/  (you can see if there is any error)